# Setting manifest attributes to phonegap app

Tags: android, xml, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a Phone-Gap application, built using the Phone-Gap Build Service, which I am trying to edit the [Android Manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) of directly, using the following code in config.xml.

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
    <!-- Manifest Tags -->
</gap:config-file>
```

This works correctly when adding child tags of the manifest such as;

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"></application>
```

However, I am having an issue when trying to add [attributes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) from the root manifest tag, such as;

- package
- android:sharedUserId

I have tried adding the manifest directly inside the [gap:config-file](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/config-file-element/) tag

```
<gap:config-file>
    <manifest android:sharedUserId="com.domain.app.sharedcontainer"></manifest>
<gap:config-file>
```

I have also tried adding the value in the root widget tag in config.xml, as that's where attributes like the *package name* is defined. Although I didn't find any documentation suggesting that would work, I thought i'd try it anyway.

```
<widget
  xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
  xmlns:cdv = "http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
  xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
  id = "com.domain.app.id"
  android: sharedUserId = "com.domain.app.sharedcontainer"
  defaultlocale = "en-GB"
  version = "1.1.0">
```

None of my approaches have worked, so my question is this;

- How do I set manifest attributes to a Phone-Gap application.